# grid search for one-class svm

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I modified the code that LIBSVM is proposing for cv grid search so as to perform grid search for a one-class SVM. So instead of searching for c, I need to search for the best pair of nu and gamma. I changed the range of C values to values 0.5 (default by libsvm), 0.6, 0.7,0.8,0.9 as nu needs to take values in (0,1).
The results I am getting is that as nu increases the cross-validation accuracy improves so eventually nu=0.9 is the best parameter for nu. This is the case when I try to train the SVM without performing cross validation grid search, and simply change nu within the range of (0.5,0.9).

However, the results of the test remain the same for all parameters of nu. My question is shouldnt the change of nu values affect the test accuracy?

This is the code LIBSVM is proposing for grid search.

```
codbestcv = 0;
for log2c = -1:3,
  for log2g = -4:1,
    cmd = ['-v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];
    cv = svmtrain(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, cmd);
    if (cv >= bestcv),
      bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g;
    end
    fprintf('%g %g %g (best c=%g, g=%g, rate=%g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg, bestcv);
  ende that follows:
```